# How to construct such a Linearly Independent subset of V having n elements

Tags: analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my assignments in Smooth manifolds and  I need help in solving this problem.

> Show that the vector space V, consisting of all linear maps $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is infinite dimensional by showing that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , there exists a linearly independent subset of V having n elements.

If $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, then it is a linear map ie f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y) , f(cx) =c f(x); for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$but I am unable to construct / think what elements will be in such a set so as I can prove it Linearly independent.

Please guide.

Comment: The elements of $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} ) $ are NOT linear maps. $C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} ) $ is the space of smooth functions from $ \mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb{R} $

Comment: @TomAriel Ya, sorry my bad. Can you please help with the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the dual space of an infinite dimensional space, so it's definitely infinite dimensional. However, you want to show this by *explicitly* showing an infinite linearly independent set.

An easy way to define functionals on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is to take evaluations at points: for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define $\hat{x}\colon C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\hat{x}(f)=f(x)$.

Can we say that if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are distinct points then $\{\hat{x}_1,\dots,\hat{x}_n\}$ is linearly independent? Suppose we have a linear combination
$$
a_1\hat{x}_1+a_2\hat{x}_2+\dots+a_n\hat{x}_n=0
$$
Thus, for *every* $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$
a_1f(x_1)+a_2f(x_2)+\dots+a_nf(x_n)=0
$$
Now it's easy. Take a polynomial $f$ such that $f(x_1)=1$ and $f(x_i)=0$ for  $i\ne 1$. This proves that $a_1=0$. Finish up.